The Ethereum has not been received
I had money on SOL, and I exchanged it for ETH, and it changed to ETH base, then I decided to send the money to another ethereum address and lost everything. PHANTOM WALLET ETHEREUM BASE:0x135c79dF873Cb19D4626A6084F64B1C49B87CD97.
ETHEREUM WALLET NO BASE: 0xe01270FDC0b856A4fc7b270E751E93BBE00B7932.  PLEASE HELP ME
